# Create similar container to website

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I've tried to display something similar like this on my **website**:

- 3 round images aligned next to each other
- a centered heading below each of the images ("ready", "add", "zap")
- a centered content text below each of the images ("Make your own ...", "...")
- two buttons centered over the width of the three images

[image: image1]

I'm pretty sure I have to make use of `display: flex` but because I'm absolutely new to **flex** I do not really get an idea how to create a container like you can see in the image on top.

This is the code I got so far *(It is not finished but I got no idea how to go on)* - so any help would be really appreciated. `:)`

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#container>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


#container>div>img {
  max-width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
      <h3>Heading 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commod</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
      <h3>Heading 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ull</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
      <h3>Heading 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ouh yes it has. Try to remove and add the `margin: auto` property. @fcalderan

Comment: Simply putting this here for the record: This layout can be done with or without flexbox. A flexbox solution is a preferred route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap each column in a div with `text-align: center` on it:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* line up divs in a row (ie make the inner divs columns */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* allows the columns to wrap to the next row */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* adds space in between the columns that fit on the same line */
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  /* 30% allows 5% space between each top row column */
  text-align: center;
  /* centre inner content of column */
}

.column img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.context {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 1em 0;
  /* 48% allows 4% space between buttons */
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  flex-basis: 48%;
  /* 48% allows 4% space between buttons */
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <h1>This is the heading 1</h1>
    <p>some text below the heading!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <h1>This is the heading 2</h1>
    <p>some text below the heading!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <h1>This is the heading 3</h1>
    <p>some text below the heading!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="context">lots of centered text can goe here or just delete this if not needed!</div>
  <div class="button left">button 1</div>
  <div class="button right">button 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a very clean solution, thanks a lot. Would you mind to add the centered context-text below the heading and above the buttons? `:)`

Comment: Ok @Jonas - just add more text in your column divs

Answer (score 0):

Since flex only allows one direction, you gonna have to start wrapping your elements, to align them as you like.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#container>div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container>div>h3 {
  align-self: center;
}

#container>div>img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
}

.btns>button {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
      <h3>Heading 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commod</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
      <h3>Heading 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ull</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
      <h3>Heading 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btns">
    <button>Text</button>
    <button>Text again</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Using CSS Grid

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

ul>li>img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

ul>li>h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.btnsContainer {
  font-size: 0;
  grid-column: 1/4
}

.btnsContainer>button {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commod</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ull</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure</p>
  </li>
  <li class="btnsContainer">
    <button>Text</button>
    <button>Text again</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey looks like a nice solution. (+1) Would you mind to add `How to edit the size of the images`? If I change the `max-width property` all looks super destroyed. Would be super nice, greetings jonas

Comment: max-width is meant so the images won't go outside the parent's width, you can still define a width, but if it goes above the parent's width, then it won't have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `flex` to achieve this result. You have to use the correct HTML structure then apply the styles.

You should wrap each pair of `img` and `label` inside a `div`. I gave it a class name `.sub`. To position the three `.sub` as three columns of equal width, you can set `width: 30%` on the first two and `margin: auto` on the last one.

Set the display property of `.sub` to `inline-block` and the job is done:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sub > img {
  width: 100%;
}

sub:last-child {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <div>This is the heading 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <div>This is the heading 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <div>This is the heading 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This however will require much more care when it comes to different screen sizes. other than that it works flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
#container
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#container .element
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

You can also replace "space-around" by "center" or "space-between" and check if it fits better your overall design.

Create 3 blocks (containing image, heading, text) each in a separate div and add them a class (the "element" above).

Answer (score 0):

To learn flexbox you can use this fun free game :https://flexboxfroggy.com/

```css
.container{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;/*put the items inside the container in a row*/
justify-content:space-around;/*items are separated with space*/
margin-top:10%;

}
figcaption {
text-align:center;
margin-top:5%;}

img{
width:200px;
border-radius:50%;

}
.column{

}

button{
display:block;/*because input tag are inline by default*/
width:48%;
margin-left:1%;
text-align:center;
background:green;
height:40px;

}
```

```html
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

  <div class="column">
    <img alt="" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <figcaption>This is the heading 1</figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <figcaption>This is the heading 1</figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
    <figcaption>This is the heading 1</figcaption>
  </div>


</div>
<div class="container">
  <button type = "submit">button 1</button>
  <button type="submit">button 2</button>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you have to set `flex-basis` for child divs in percentage and aligned them with `center`. here I did this with the class name `item`, and set parent div with `display:flex` and `justify-content: space-between`.

**Note**: you can also go with `space-around` instead of `space-between` as per your convenience.

### html

```
<div class="container bxp">
 <div class="item item1">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div  class="item item2">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div  class="item item3">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fa/89/6c/fa896c405abec656a0c8516229fa55ad.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.bxp{
  max-width: 1000px;
  display:flex;
  margin:auto;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.item{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}
img{
  width:100px;
}
```